How to save input=file submitted files in cache to display them in browser and only upload after a few steps (javascript/php)
I'm creating a file upload/edit tool for a photography company where the users should be able to upload multiple photos, view them, select some options for each of them, then go to the shopping cart and pay for their order. I want to only actually upload the photos to the server after they've submitted the shopping cart, so that's a few steps later. I also want them to be able to go back to the editing page and see the photos they upload and change the options before going back to the shopping cart. I'd like to save the photos in cookies or in the php $_SESSION variable or somewhere else so that I can still access them after the page has been refreshed or the user has navigated somewhere else on the site.
I'm using JavaScript and PHP
What I'm doing right now is, using javascript, when the files are dropped into the box, the file type input receives the files and then for each file, i create a div with the image in it and use
URL.createObjectURL(file)
to get the local path for the file. This works, the images do appear. My problem is that after submitting the form, I don't know how to save the files in order to later be able to access them in the same way. I'm now saving the URL.createObjectURL(file) in a cookie, but then when i access that cookie with javascript, the path no longer works.

You can't save it in $_SESSION without uploading, since that only exists on the server.

You could use localStorage or sessionStorage, those are client-side storage. Cookies are much more limited, you probably couldn't save images there.

Keep in mind, that session storage size is only 5 MB and local storage 10 MB. Cookies are only 4 KB.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

i've now tried saving them to localStorage in base64 but just one image already throws "Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of '7photos' exceeded the quota." so i am now trying to submit the form and then convert each image to base64 using PHP to then put them in the $_SESSION variable in base64 but how do i convert an uploaded file directly to base64 without saving the actual file anywhere?
